# Regular expression must end with gmail.com or start with 1234 Is Either or Possible?

Tags: regex

Can you specify that it must do one or the other?

Comment: What flavor of regex php perl .net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's an inclusive OR, sure:

```
/(?:^1234|gmail\.com$)/
```

If it's an exclusive OR, the simplest way is to do it with two expressions: test whether it matches exactly one of `/^1234/` or `/gmail\.com$/`.